# Where to place custom beamer themes

Tags: beamer, texmf

I've created a custom theme for `beamer` that I plan to use for multiple presentations. So, while I currently have the `.sty` file (just one at this point, as I load an inner theme and color theme, then define the outer theme) in the same directory as the presentation I'm working on now, I want it available in the future without have to maintain multiple copies.

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files), I understand I can install packages in my home texmf folder (e.g. `~/texmf` on Linux, which is where I do most of my work), however should I then structure my texmf folder like the beamer subdirectory in the main texmf folder (i.e. `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes/[color,font,inner,outer,theme]` on my Ubuntu machine), or just put put down any/all `.sty` files in the single directory.

Note, while I mentioned I do most of my work on Linux, answers for OS X and Windows would be useful, as I do work on both of these platforms as well - and frequently sync files between machines via Git repositories.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should copy the first two folder levels of the main tree (in your example tex/latex). Everything below this point is optional. You can use additional subfolders and name them at your liking. Use your sense of order. I would certainly make at least a subfolder "beamer".

Comment: Thanks - good to know the rest of the tree past tex/latex is not necessary.

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same trouble and fix it differently. Two main things to know :
 - the beamer command `\usetheme` is indeed the same as `\usepackage` apart from the fact that it concatenates the argument with `beamertheme`
 - you can specify backward directories to `\usepackage` with `../`

Using these two points you only need to know the relative path from your `.tex` to your `.sty`; and then can organise the stuff easily.

A quick example: on a given drive `D`, you have your `.tex` in `D:/beamer/files` and you put some themes in `D:/beamer/themes`, then to use a given theme *mytheme* from the file `beamerthememytheme.sty` in `D:/beamer/themes`, you add in the `.tex` file `\usepackage{../themes/beamerthememytheme}` instead of `\usetheme{mytheme}`

not sure if it works on windows however

Comment: Could you please have a look to the comments [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111629/13304) about this approach?

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation of the command `\usetheme`