# Nice custom beamer theme: how to do something like it?

Tags: beamer, presentations

So I found this totally awesome looking presentation that's made in LaTeX: https://web.archive.org/web/20160812023301/http://pyprop.googlecode.com/files/disputas.pdf

I love how there is custom header with university logo. I'd like to do something like that (different university obviously XD), and I would like to find out how to do sth like that.

From what I've read on beamer manual, I only find a way how to put custom background image, but this seems to be modified theme.

And I don't want to send e-mail to the person who did this presentation (it would be totally embarrassing), but I would like to find out how to do sth like that.

Any suggestions, sites with code that does sth like this?

Any help is appreciated ^^

Comment: Wow, every  upvoter has favourited (I think). '

Comment: Well it's an interesting question :D And the answer is really great :)

Comment: I found another presentation that looks really nice. It's really simple, but the color combination is great :)
http://www.phys.chuo-u.ac.jp/labs/inami/seminarfile/2012/5Hikida.pdf
I'll try to recreate it, if I succeed I'll give the code here :)

Comment: I uploaded it here: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/475744/presentation-rar.html
It's not perfect, far from that it needs some heavy adjusting, but for start it's not bad. If anyone wants it, please use it :)

Comment: Wow agree with you, this is a wonderful theme. I encounter your question on the way to find a nice beamer them and fell in love with this one right away.

Comment: @dingo_d: It seems the link in your comment is dead. Can you please repost it some where (like git ot bitbucket) so that it doesn't die off?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be that way. I created a git repo for the presentation, please use it and improve it as you wish, and feel free to post how it looks like :) https://github.com/dingo-d/LaTeX-presentation

Comment: The link in the post is dead; but it can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20160812023301/http://pyprop.googlecode.com/files/disputas.pdf

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You'll need to create a .sty file and install it like described here:
[Where to place custom beamer themes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/where-to-place-custom-beamer-themes)

A sweet tutorial about customizing beamer themes (via Wayback Machine):

https://web.archive.org/web/20130724090805/http://www.math.umbc.edu:80/~rouben/beamer/quickstart-Z-H-8.html

You can also find examples to modify: http://latex.simon04.net/

Here's a particularly good one (via Wayback Machine):

https://web.archive.org/web/20151005203517/http://www.matdat.life.ku.dk:80/LaTeX/Frederiksberg/download/

This 4 may be a good starting point for customization, check out the files under 'color' directory to change theme (via Wayback Machine):

https://web.archive.org/web/20111210142341/http://staff.science.uva.nl/~faolieho/index.php?fuseaction=var.beamer

The [antwerpen](http://win.ua.ac.be/~nschloe/content/ua-beamer-theme) theme is nice, and provides examples for using images.

```
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\textlogoheight]{uTextColor}{logo_UA_tekst_kl}%
\ifthenelse{ \boolean{beamer@dark} \OR \boolean{beamer@darktitle} }%
% then
{\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{uaBackgroundDark}{uaBackgroundDarkBlue}}%
%else
{}%
```

Comment: 1 - http://www.math.umbc.edu/~rouben/beamer/quickstart-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_8 2 - http://latex.simon04.net/ 3 - http://matdat.life.ku.dk/LaTeX/Frederiksberg/download/ 4 - http://staff.science.uva.nl/~faolieho/index.php?fuseaction=var.beamer

Comment: someone with more rep please edit to add links to answer?

Answer (score 18):

if it's still of interest:
A template that is very similar and I think the guy that made the presentation you mentioned gave some advise...

http://www.drbunsen.org/custom-beamer-theme.html

Comment: I really liked the presentation you linked to. Thus, I started searching for the original file. Guess what? The author GRACIOUSLY made the entire source file and sty file available. Here is the link
https://code.google.com/p/pyprop/downloads/list Enjoy!

Comment: I got the error Package keyval Error: frametitle undefined. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 11):

I have ported a PowerPoint and a Powerdot theme to Beamer. They are available [here](https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports).