# LaTeX presentations like OpenOffice .odp

Tags: beamer, books

I've been reading of `beamer` to make presentations with LaTeX, so I'd like a good book to perform these tasks.

Is there a good book (or website) for that?

Comment: Once you got a nice Beamer presentation and in case you are using Linux, I can recommend the pdf-presenter-console http://westhoffswelt.de/projects/pdf_presenter_console.html which is already included in distributions like Ubuntu.

Comment: Fine thanks, I'm GNU/Linux user. So pdf-presenter-console is the perfect choice

Comment: @Christian It seems that project is deprecated now in favor of https://pdfpc.github.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) is filled with examples.
2. When it comes to choosing an associated style for your presentation, consider the [`beamer` theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/). Customization of themes are also possible. For example, see [Nice custom beamer theme: how to do something like it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15067/5764)
3. Tutorials are also abundant online by just [searching in Google for *`beamer` tutorial*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=beamer+tutorial).

Comment: Beamer theme matrix, an awesome site!