# MSc thesis presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I have completed  my MSc Thesis and now I want to create a presentation slide. I have got a  good physics template which from Cambridge university.

The pdf link is  http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/research/gr/workshops/PASCOS/2011/presentations/Amin-pascos2011.pdf.

Can you please give me the Latex or source file or similar presentations beamer/

Comment: Which special stuff do you expect from such a "physics template"?

Comment: How much time left do you have for the presentation? I mean, if it's your first time with `beamer` and friends, it might require some time to understand the nuts and bolts. `:)`

Comment: `<lame physics joke>` If we consider the multiverse theory, your presentation is already done somewhere. `:)` `</lame physics joke>`

Comment: You can look http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15067/nice-custom-beamer-theme-how-to-do-something-like-it and in the links provided therein :)

Comment: The time lag might be 15 to 20 mins

Comment: Maybe you can as the original author of the presentation to provide you with a skeleton LaTeX file. I seem to have found his work website including email after minimal time asking a search engine...

Comment: First as you can see it's from MIT. Second it's a Powerpoint presentation or Keynote. So please show us something that YOU did and ask which part you wish to improve.

Comment: Check it's properties, it shows Creator: `Apple Keynote 5.0.5` Producer: `Mac OS X 10.5.8 Quartz PDFContext`. It's not done using latex

Comment: Can't I create by latex or can't I find alike the template?

Comment: @ComplexGuy I have no idea where and how you create alike template but i know one can tinker/tweak `beamer` to get an equivalent color and design with some effort. May be if you post an first attempt MWE, people may help to improve.

Comment: Okay I am trying. but can you give me any source file so I can put my info in the  file?

Comment: The question is quite clear, but it lacks self effort even though the right keywords were presented. Since the question ask to *get the look* it is a *do it for me question*. I vote to close as *too broad*.