# path for outhertheme in beamer templates

Tags: beamer, templates, paths

I want to store my templates in the same folder as my presentations. I have created templates using a file `beamertemplatefoo.sty` that contains :

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{foo}
\useinnertheme{foo}
\usecolortheme{foo}
```

I have a subdirectory for each presentation. If I put all the 4 templates files in the subdirectory, I can simply call `\usetemplate{foo}`.

However, it is not very clean to have multiples occurences of the same file. I could symlink them to some file in the directory containing all the presentations but I was rather thinking of using [Where to place custom beamer themes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/where-to-place-custom-beamer-themes) to call `beamertemplatefoo.sty` outside of the subdirectory using a `\usepackage{../templates/beamertemplatefoo}`.  This searches outer and inner templates (and color theme) in the subdirectory where my `.tex` file is located. How can I manage such decomposition of my template puting all file in a subdirectory ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to move the `templates` folder to a location where latex can find it, see [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) for more details.

---

If you want to keep your current folder structure, your beamer theme could call the subthemes in the same way as you call your main theme:

```
\usepackage{../templates/beamerouterthemefoo}
```